# Find the minimum distance between two convex hulls

Tags: convex-polytopes, convex-geometry, linear-programming, convex-optimization

We work over $\mathbb{R}^N$. Let $\mathbf{P}_1$ denote the hyperplane constructed using $N$ points, each of which is on a different axis (there are $N$ axes). We denote by $\mathbf{P}_2$ the convex hull of a set of $M$ points, but we don't know which of these points are the vertices.
I am trying to find the minimum distance between $\mathbf{P}_1$, which can also be seen as a convex hull, and $\mathbf{P}_2$.

My approach is to define an optimization problem having an acceptable computational complexity. My question is how can we define such a problem ?

Comment: It may help to look at the CGAL implementation [*here*](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polytope_distance_d/classCGAL_1_1Polytope__distance__d.html). CGAL formulates it "as an optimization problem with linear constraints and a convex quadratic objective function." They then use an exact solver for quadratic programs.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke It's not clear [_here_](http://people.inf.ethz.ch/gaertner/texts/own_work/qp-solver.pdf) (section 5.1) if $P$ (or $Q$) is the set of vertices or not. In my case, for $\mathbf{P}_2$ I don't have the set of vertices alone, but a set of $M$ points which contains the vertices and other points ( which will be inside the convex hull constructed using these vertices)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is discussed at length [here.](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/224108603_A_Fast_Geometric_Algorithm_for_Finding_the_Minimum_Distance_Between_Two_Convex_Hulls) (Kaown and Liu, 2009)

Comment: Maybe this is a dumb question, but when they wrote "Given the set $X=\left\{ x_1,\dots,x_m \right\}$. Let the convex hull be $U=\left\{ \sum_i^m\alpha_ix_i \, .. \right\}$... " do they consider the set $X$ as the set of vertices or a set of points that contains the vertices and other points (that will be inside the convex hull)? Thank you

Comment: The way they write it makes one think that these are the vertices.

Comment: I am asking this since in my case I don't know the set of vertices for $\mathbf{P}_2$.

Comment: Reading the paper seems to indicate that they don't need $X$ to be the set of vertices.

Comment: One more question please. In this paper, they don't provide an expression that capture the computational complexity of their algorithm. If we define the problem as a QP (as done [_here_](http://people.inf.ethz.ch/gaertner/texts/own_work/qp-solver.pdf)), do you think that their algorithm outperforms the interior point method (as instance) used to solve the QP ?

Comment: I don't know (and these kinds of questions are hard to answer, since worst case complexity generally tells very little about real-life performance), but the graphs in the back of the paper look quite promising.

Comment: My last question (if you please). It seems that, finally, my problem is reduced to find the minimum distance between a hyperplane and a convex hull. Do you think that I should ask this as a seperate question or you can provide me with some references here?

Comment: @mat to find the miniumum distance between a hyperplane and a convex hull of a point set, just compute the distances between the points in the point set and hyperplane, and take the minimum. Nothing fancy required.

Comment: But maybe the minimum distance is between the hyperplane and a point that lies on the convex hull and not necessarily a point form the set (but a convex combination of the points in this set). Thus, I think we should consider a point as the convex combination of the points in the set and try to minimize the distance between this point and the hyperplane. What do you think?